# Could not synchronize database state with session

Tags: hibernate, jdbc

Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not update

I am getting this error while I try to update my database. There is no unique key defined in my database, but id field has been defined as Primary Key.

Here is the code of the update function :

```
public String updateAction(){
       Session session = null;
       try{
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session =sessionFactory.openSession();
            org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Medicine medicine = (Medicine) session.load(Medicine.class, id);
            medicine.setBrandName(brandName);
            session.update(medicine);
            tx.commit();
       }
       catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
       }
       finally{
            session.close();
       }
       return "index";
    }
```

hibernate.config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/medicine</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.factory_class">org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcherFactory</property>
    <mapping resource="mediview/Medicine.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Medicine.java:

```
    public class Medicine  implements java.io.Serializable {

         private String id;
         private String brandName;

         public Medicine() {
         }

     public Medicine(String id) {
          this.id = id;
     }

     public Medicine(String id, String brandName) {
          this.id = id;
          this.brandName = brandName;
     }

     public String getId() {
          return this.id;
     }

     public void setId(String id) {
          this.id = id;
     }

     public String getBrandName() {
          return this.brandName;
     }

    public void setBrandName(String brandName) {
        this.brandName = brandName;
    }
}
```

Medicine.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 14 Aug, 2013 8:46:46 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="mediview.Medicine" table="medicine" catalog="medicine">
        <id name="id" type="string">
            <column name="ID" length="5" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="brandName" type="string">
            <column name="BrandName" length="30" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you give us the entity and maybe the hibernate config?

Comment: I just added the hibernate config file.

Comment: Thanks, and then I think we might need "mediview/Medicine.hbm.xml".

Comment: I added Medicine.hbm.xml too.

Comment: This all looks good. Not sure about your error. Your database schema is correct? Have you tried the SQL hibernate generates? You can switch this on via hibernate.show_sql property.

Comment: I'm not sure what went wrong, but as soon as I restarted the fish server, it started working fine. I also did write session refresh command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a refresh of the session state before you do the update.

```
Medicine medicine = (Medicine) session.load(Medicine.class, id);
session.refresh( medicine );
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d0e1718

Comment: @Arun But why refresh is required in this case  ?

Comment: is there a way i could do this in the webservice client? like get the existing session and refresh the object before saving it?