# Hibernate session not synchronize when deadlock detected

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, database-deadlocks

I have following scenario to save my object

```
// Started transaction
User objUser = getUser("123");// get user from DB
objUser.set(...)
.
.
UserAddress objUserAddress = objUser.getUserAddress();
objUserAddress.set(..);
.
.
hibernateSession.flush(); //#Line 1
hibernateSession.saveOrUpdate(objUserAddress); //#Line 2
hibernateSession.flush(); //#Line 3
hibernateSession.saveOrUpdate(objUser); //#Line 4
// Commit transaction
```

Here is hibernate mapping between User and Address class

```
<class name="com.service.core.bo.impl.User" table="USERS">
.
.
<many-to-one name="userAddress" class="com.service.core.bo.impl.UserAddress"
        column="ADDRESS_ID" not-null="false" unique="true" cascade="save-update"
        lazy="false" />
.
.
</class>
```

At some time I received deadlock on #Line 1. here is exception stack.

```
[2017-12-12 11:15:02.131 GMT] WARN [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] http-bio-8280-exec-14 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 60, SQLState: 61000
[2017-12-12 11:15:02.131 GMT] ERROR [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] http-bio-8280-exec-14 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

[2017-12-12 11:15:02.131 GMT] ERROR [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] http-bio-8280-exec-14 org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:172)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor706.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       .
       .
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:12296)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:246)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor553.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.StatementProxyFactory.invoke(StatementProxyFactory.java:353)
        at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.PreparedStatementProxyFactory.invoke(PreparedStatementProxyFactory.java:178)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
        ... 71 more
```

Problem is, this error is not consistent. This may occur once or multiple times in a day and other day, nothing.
Not sure why `flush()` causing `Could not synchronize database state with session` and `ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource`. I found some links like [Could not synchronize database state with session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559714/could-not-synchronize-database-state-with-session) for session state but my actual cause is deadlock as per above exception.

Answer (score 4):

**Could not synchronize database state with session** is an generic hibernate error that can have multiple root causes. 
The error that you should focus on is:

**ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource**

This is Oracle specific and it happens when updates to the same data (row in the database) is happening from more then one connection. Whenever Oracle (and just about any database, in fact) it updates a row, it locks it for the duration of the update. If another update is attempted on the same line while it is locked, then this error happens. 
Here is the official error explanation from Oracle:

ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

Cause: Transactions deadlocked one another while waiting for resources.

Action: Look at the trace file to see the transactions and resources involved. Retry if necessary.

One way to address this problem is to use versioning:

https://www.intertech.com/Blog/versioning-optimistic-locking-in-hibernate/

This adds a version column to the table, which is automatically incremented when the row is updated. Before the update the version is checked and if it is higher then the one expected, the updated is not even updated and a specific error is thrown, which you can handle. Usually handling involves reloading the info from the database for that entity, reset its values to what you want and then save.

Comment: Thanks and apology  for delay in response. You are correct that deadlock happened when two resources trying to update at a same time. But here in my case, I am getting this exception on `flush()` method only.

Comment: Yes, that is normal, because only then the changes you are making are actually applied to the database. saveOrUpdate() will not do database operations, everything is done when you call flush().